# How do you write for each $x$ between $x_1$ to $x_2$ inclusive?

Tags: notation, real-numbers

I am trying to write the mathematical representation of the following:

For each $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ (inclusive).

I am thinking that the below may be correct, although I am not 100% sure it comes across as I intend:

$$\forall x\in\{x_1,x_2\}$$

Comment: I would  read that as saying that $x$ was one of $x_1$ or $x_2$.  I suggest "$\forall x$ such that $x_1≤x≤x_2$", trusting that you have $x_1≤x_2$.

Comment: You should say for all $x$ satisfying $x_1 \leq x \leq x_2$. The expression you wrote means "for all $x$ which is exactly one of $x_1$ or $x_2$".

Comment: Yea I was reading it as x is exactly x1 or x2 but how you have wrote it looks relevant to what I was trying to state. Thanks guys

Comment: I would suggest $\forall x \in [x_1,x_2]$, as the square brackets indicate the closed (i.e. inclusive) boundary of an interval. Similarly, for an exclusive boundary, you can use parentheses. And you can mix both, like in $y \in [a,b)$, meaning that you can have $y=a$ but you cannot have $y=b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this: $\forall x\in [x_1,x_2]$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals

Comment: So where i used curly braces around x1, x2, would this signify that x was exactly x1 or x2? and how you have used square brackets would mean its between x1 and x2?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  And $\forall x\in(x_1,x_2)$ would mean the "open" interval without the endpoints.

Comment: Okay thanks for that!